# Is block between negative #if #endif statement visible after decompilation?

Tags: c#

Are lines followed by negative #if statement cleared from the code or are they just 'not used'? In c++ I understood that preprocessor just cleared that but in c# there is no preprocessor so functionality can vary a little. I was looking a little but not found clear statement about this in documentation.

```
#if PRIVATE
string password = "pass";
#else
string password;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part in between the pre-processor directives are excluded and not visible in the eventually intermediate language when the predicate evaluates to false.

There is no proof of it ever existed once the compiler has run. You have nothing to worry about here.